# Resolving class conflict between 2 jars

Tags: java, android, class, conflict

I have a problem in my Android application. Among the jars I use, there is the android.jar and the rt.jar.

In both jars, exists the class org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory. The class from android.jar is being used, but I want to use the class from rt.jar. How can I make my project choose the class I want? Can't I do it for this specific class only (meaning not always in case of conflict the class from rt.jar will be chosen over the class from android.jar).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why do you want to be using rt.jar at all?

Comment: Because I get classNotFound exception when using the XMLReaderFactory of the android.jar

Comment: No, I mean: why do you want to depend on rt.jar in your project? It doesn't seem like the right thing to be doing for an Android app, since the run-time environment does not have any of these classes.

Comment: In the build path order and export list, try moving rt.jar on top of android.jar and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of resolving this. You can and have to remove the class from one binary. By doing this you violate LGPL type licenses but in android all the classes are getting built into a single apk making such licenses meaningless in the context.

alternatively you can [give that responsibility to build system.](http://java.dzone.com/news/jarjar-solves-class-loading-co)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me

Go to

```
    Build Path --> select the JRE System Library --> Remove it.
    Select Add library --> Jre System Library --> default 
(i think default will be already selected) --> Ok
```